# Novelty detection using one class svm-python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm in the process of novelty detection using machine-learning. I have tried using one-class svm in [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html).

```
from sklearn import svm

train_data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]]
test_data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]


clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1)
clf.fit(train_data)

pred_test = clf.predict(test_data)
```

I'm new to this area and I want to know how can I say there is novelty in my test data?

Answer (score 2):

The inliers are labeled 1, and the outliers (i.e., the novelties in your case) are labeled -1 (as the result of the `predict` function).

Please notice that the [current documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) incorrectly states that the outliers are labeled 1 & inliers are labeled 0. Please check out the latest updates on [github repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/doc/modules/outlier_detection.rst) for the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

check = clf.predict(test_data)

if check = 1 then not anomaly and

if check = -1 then it an anomaly i.e. data is outlier